# how can i create many directional links between agents in anylogic to find the speed of distribution of information

Tags: networking, hyperlink, anylogic, agent

the theme of my project is “The Study of the Speed of Content Distribution Taking Into Account Non-directional and Directional Links in Social Media”. I create type of agent: “user”, create the network in “Main”, create the state chart for “SI” and “SIR” for spreading the information.
The network type for bidirectional connections is dimensionless, I set the connections in the “connections” element, the distribution of information goes smoothly (the example of undirectec connection is “friends in social network”
But to create directed links(the example is one blogger and his subscribers), the type of network is "random", how can I model the distribution of information between agents “User” within the network to show the direction of propagation?  Is it necessary to separately create a so-called agent “blogger” to which ordinary “users” agents will “subscribe” using “unidirectional link to agent”?

I try to add a unidirectional link, but i don’t understand how to show the directed connection of one “user” to another